# How to set a redelivery policy in RabbitMQ/AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, amqp

I'm currently using ActiveMQ for my queueing system, and I'm wanting to make the transition to RabbitMQ. One feature I've been using that belongs to ActiveMQ is a redelivery policy, as sometimes our consumer rejects a message because it cannot handle it at this time, but may want to try again later, so it requeues it.

Right now in AMQP, when I reject a message, it's instantly pulled off the queue again immediately and tried again.

Is there a way, in RabbitMQ, to specify a redelivery policy for a queue, consumer, or message?

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with that behaviour. According to documentation (as far as I remember, maybe in newer version something changed) after requeue it is not stated where a message will be placed (it was described as undetermined). In my testcases (with version 2.8.2) some of messages were put to the end of a queue and one message (precisely first from clients prefetch) land on beggining (and being consumed immediately). In our application this caused livelock.

You could walkaround this by publishing copy of message to a queue and acking already delivered one in one transaction (but I recommend to carefully read section about transactions in docs) or use deadlettering to deal with temporaly unprocessable messages.

Comment: In the version I'm using, which I believe to be the latest, their API provides a way of rejecting the message, and either requeueing it, or sending to a DLQ. Currently I like the DLQ as a retry queue, but I am used to the ActiveMQ solution where you can basically throttle retry's.